# How to use unique key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

How to use unique key SQL Server 2014? If table has been created.

Comment: It depends on your table and your needs. Not every table should ever has unique key constraint defined.

Comment: Is it so hard to use Google?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: That's a primary key not a unique key... but yes all this information is on google.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    COL1,
    COL2
)
```